# Console colored text changes string length

Tags: python, colorama

In Windows,
The Colored Console Text module called `colorama` changes colors but it also changes string length too.

How do I avoid this?

My Code:

```
from colorama import * #Not only colorama
init(convert=True)

my_text = Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX+"Hello World!"
print(mytext, len(my_text))

#Output: Hello World! 17
```

So I want 12 length but module adds 5 more characters.

Comment: It's because you've added characters to the string with the `Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX+…`.

Comment: Can I get 12 length with color?

Comment: You could create your own ColoredText string class that kept the text characters separate from the color assigned to them. yet acted mostly like a regular string otherwise (i.e. such as with respect to value `len()` returns).

Answer (score 4):

This is because to add colour they are adding hidden characters to the start of the string that tells the thing displaying it to use a colour. You can look at the actual value of you text by printing it like this:

```
from colorama import * #Not only colorama
init(convert=True)

my_text = Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX+"Hello World!"
print(repr(my_text), len(my_text))
```

which will output `'\x1b[96mHello World!' 17`

If you want to keep getting the length of the text perhaps you would be better off storing it in the variable as "Hello World!" and only adding Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX when displaying it

Comment: Late reply but I want to add colorful characters to my roguelike console game. When I use color modules it breaks my game. Can I avoid this?